# Context is disposed when triggering Quartz job in Asp.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a trigger a Quartz job from a Web API controller in .NET core.
I already succeed to create a trigger with a simple schedule from the **Startup** class :

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

            app.UseMvc();

            ProcessTracksScheduler.Start(services);          
        }
```

Here is the start method :

```
 public static class ProcessTracksScheduler
    {
        public static void Start(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            try
            {
                ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
                sched.Start();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ProcessTracksJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("ProcessTracks", "Group1")
                    .Build();

                job.JobDataMap["tracksService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(ITracksService));
                job.JobDataMap["cloudService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(ICloudService));
                job.JobDataMap["broadcastService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(IBroadcastService));
                job.JobDataMap["categoriesService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(ICategoriesService));

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .RepeatForever()
                        .WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)))
                    .StartNow()
                    .Build();

                sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                // Log the error
            }
        }
   }
```

And the Job :

```
public async void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var tracksService = context.MergedJobDataMap["tracksService"] as ITracksService;
    var cloudService = context.MergedJobDataMap["cloudService"] as ICloudService;
    var broadcastService = context.MergedJobDataMap["broadcastService"] as IBroadcastService;
    var categoryService = context.MergedJobDataMap["categoriesService"] as ICategoriesService;

    if (tracksService == null || cloudService == null || broadcastService == null || categoryService == null)
        return;

    var broadcasts = broadcastService.GetAll();
    // Some more work to do.
}
```

So this one works as expected, I'm very happy with it ! But the problem here is when I'm trying to build a trigger for the job to start only once from my web API controller :

```
[Route("Proccess")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProccessTracks()
{
    ProcessTracksScheduler.StartOnce(serviceProvider);
    return Ok("Job scheduled");
}
```

And the **StartOnce** method, basically the same as the Start :

```
public static void StartOnce(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    try
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ProcessTracksJob>()
            .WithIdentity("ProcessTracksOnce", "Group1")
            .Build();

        job.JobDataMap["tracksService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(ITracksService));
        job.JobDataMap["cloudService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(ICloudService));
        job.JobDataMap["broadcastService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(IBroadcastService));
        job.JobDataMap["categoriesService"] = provider.GetService(typeof(ICategoriesService));

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        // Log the error
    }
}
```

BUT there when my job is executed, the line `var broadcasts = broadcastService.GetAll();` throws an exception saying that my **DbContext** is disposed..

The DbContext is passed through DI to the controllers/services with ASP.Net-Core :

```
// In Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnString")));
    services.AddTransient<IBroadcastService, BroadcastsService>();
    // Add the others services.        
}
```

I tried a lot of thing, but can't found any solution to this problem.

Comment: Is your Quartz code running *inside* your ASP.NET application? If so, you shouldn't be doing that. ASP.NET is for short running tasks, and then it ends. By extending it (eg running Quartz) inside it, you are going against the principle of ASP.NET. It will terminate whenever its lifetime ends. Instead your application should be communicating with a dedicated process that contains your Quartz code.

Comment: My Quartz code is in another project, not in my ASP.NET application. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Is that project creating an executable?

Comment: No, you're right then. The quartz job is executed in the ASP.NET application. But it's not really a problem for now, the job is not heavy at all.

Comment: Doesn't matter how heavy it is, you have no control over when ASP.NET and IIS will recycle the app pool, or any number of possibilities. Anything running more than a few seconds has the potential to be terminated. So as you can imagine, trying to schedule something to run a whole day in the future will never work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll begin with this :) Any good links ?

Comment: Look into writing a Windows Service that will host Quartz. You will then need a way to communicate from your ASP.NET app to that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to require the services in your `ProcessTracksJob` class in the constructor? I'm using it like this with no problems.

Insert of using `JobDataMap` try it like this:

```
public class ProcessTracksJob :IJob 
{
   private readonly ITracksService _tracksService;

   public ProcessTracksJob(ITracksService tracksService, etc.) 
   {
     _tracksService = tracksService;
     ...
   }

   /// the execute method using the private fields in this class

}
```

Comment: If your class is derived from `IJob` then it will execute the method with no problems. Also, remember to register it in your DI library to be able to inject those services in the constructor. I'm using this approach with no problem. Is there any errors you are getting?

Comment: No errors at all, put a breakpoint in the execute method, but it will not hit it..
By register it in my DI library, do you meant something like this : ``services.AddTransient<IJob, ProcessTracksJob>();`` in ``ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)`` method ?

Comment: For DI I'm using the Job class like this: `builder.RegisterType<ProcessTracksJob>().AsSelf();`(Autofac). The quartz configuration is the same for me. For testing I use a smaller time span for the triggers.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use Autofac for this as Asp.NET-core already handle DI...

Comment: It's probably the lifetime that has expired, have you tried different lifespan services? (scoped, singleton)